# Strange npm error when running npm install brain.js

Tags: javascript, python, npm, brain.js

When trying to install `brain.js`, a strange error occurs and I can't understand what the problem is and where does the python come in since this is the installation of a library through `npm`. I didn't find similar situations in Google (I don’t even understand *how* to google this).

```
G:\firststep\BR>npm i brain.js

> gl@4.3.3 install G:\firststep\BR\node_modules\gl
> prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild

prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=10.14.2 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)

G:\firststep\BR\node_modules\gl>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 2
gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python27\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python37\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python 2.7.
gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:303:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:132:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:221:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:267:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (child_process.js:301:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:313:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:238:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\rafae\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd G:\firststep\BR\node_modules\gl
gyp ERR! node -v v10.14.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'G:\firststep\BR\package.json'
npm WARN BR No description
npm WARN BR No repository field.
npm WARN BR No README data
npm WARN BR No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gl@4.3.3 install: `prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the gl@4.3.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-14T18_48_29_640Z-debug.log
```

There is not a word about this problem in the documentation for `brain.js`. Everything is simple there - run `npm install brain.js` and that's it.

### UPDATE 16.08.2019

**This instruction marked option 2 helped me**
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows

Comment: have you got python installed? [python](https://www.python.org/downloads)

Comment: @DanStarns As soon as I saw the error after installation brain.js, I immediately installed the python of the latest version (3.7.4)

Comment: But the message says `gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python 2.7` - presumably gyp needs python 2.7, not python 3.7.4. There are incompatibilities between the two versions.

Comment: may I point you to the node gyp installation, making sure if you are running windows that you install the correct python version [node gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation)

Comment: @DanStarns yes! You were right. Brain.js had nothing to do with it. It was necessary to install correctly node gyp.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Path and Env variables are set for the Python installed. Also, I found something similar [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1268).. hope it helps!!

Comment: installed python version 2.7, but the error remained. I’ll continue the search for your link.

Comment: please tell me how to make Path and Env for python. I have OS Windows.

Comment: Based on the Windows version you have, You can refer to the steps here..https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path Also, once set, you can verify the Python version by running the command  "python -V" or ''python --version" in your command prompt.

Comment: Thank you, This tool helped me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2q_b4ugPWk

Comment: Great, Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Use the command without dot:

```
npm install brainjs
```

Comment: That's a different package