# cannot install BrainJS on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to create a neural network using javascript. So, I found brain JS, and I'm following this tutorial.

https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js#brainjs

First of all, the installation : `npm install brain.js` Then I change it to `npm install brain` So the errors are fixed.

Now I'm using visual studio and I tryed to run this first line but :

```
const brain = require('brain.js');
```

I got

```
Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: brain is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

Try  the same command without the dot:

```
npm install brainjs
```

as described in
[Strange npm error when running npm install brain.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57500514/strange-npm-error-when-running-npm-install-brain-js)

Comment: It helps me I don't have errors in the npm brainJS installation

Comment: but I still have the problem when execution the code ```Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: brain is not defined ```